# Android - AppWidgetProvider refresh content after configure activity

Tags: android, android-activity, refresh, android-appwidget

I've got a configuration activity fired from an appWidget button. If some parameters for the app are changed within the configuration activity, once saved those i should close the current activity (finish()) and refresh the appWidjet textviews content. Any chance I can force the refresh/update?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update appswidget from any activity on any event in app:

```
 RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.appswidget);
 views.setTextViewText(R.id.txtInfo, "Tiwari");
 ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(v.getContext(), WidgetProvider.class);
 AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(InfoActivity.this);
 manager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, views);
```

here RemoteViews view that will updated here, and by manager.updateAppWidget(), onUpdate() of AppWidgetProvider will called and refresh on appWidget.

you will get [here](http://www.androiddevblog.net/android/creating-appwidget-in-android-part-1) a good demo.

Comment: the problem is that i'm on an AppWidgetProvider and i run the config Activity with this:

Comment: Intent configIntent = new Intent(context, ConfigureActivity.class);
   configIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
   configIntent.setAction(ACTION_UPDATE);

   PendingIntent configPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, configIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
   remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.config_button, configPendingIntent);

Comment: I could i use startActivityForResult on appWidget Button?

Comment: first, I dint get your question before, now I have edit it have a look and feel free for discussion

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you send a broadcast message to the widget from the configuration activity.
The same broadcast message that you will send otherwise to it when you want to refresh its state.

```
Intent refreshIntent = new Intent(this, WidgetProvider.class);
refreshIntent.setAction(WidgetProvider.ACTION_RELOAD);
refreshIntent.putExtra(WidgetProvider.EXTRA_WIDGET_ID, widgetId); 
sendBroadcast(refreshIntent);
```

On the WidgetProvider you just process the new message received

```
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
            // do your stuff here on ACTION_RELOAD
    }
```